# why doesn't my 'npx expo start' outputs a QR code?

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

I am new to using react-native, i want to use the expo go app to visualize my project i created a new project and when running 'npx expo start' i expect a qr code to be outputed but no such thing happens, here is my config and output :
[config and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKIqd.png)
This is the output in 'http://localhost:8081/'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O082i.png)
i tried using this adress in the app but impossible to access it.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall node, npm and expo but it didn't work.